# Update DateTime type in mysql using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, datetime

I have a DateTime field in my database. I am using `hibernate` and `spring mvc` framework. I am able to insert DateTime field.If I update the DateTimeFiled then hour, min and seconds are set to zero.

Here is my code:

```
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd  
    HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = cd.getStartTimeFrom(); 

    System.out.println("input for dao date is "+formattedDate);

    Date tmp= new Date();
    try {
    tmp= sdf1.parse(formattedDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    //  TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
 }


       Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
       ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
       registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
       ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
       SessionFactory sessionFactory =             
       configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
       Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
       Query query=session.createQuery("update FeedFile set   
       priority=:priority, startTime=:startTime where id=:id");
       query.setInteger("id", cd.getId());
       query.setDate("startTime",tmp);
       System.out.println("---- Priority : "+ cd.getPriority());
       query.setInteger("priority", cd.getPriority());
       modifications = query.executeUpdate();
       session.getTransaction().commit();
```

If I have the record with value `2015-11-19 03:05:22` and if I update the date value using above code to `2015-11-25 09:06:12` then op is `2015-11-25 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

use in your class definition

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 private java.util.Date yourDateField;
```

or in your class.hbm.xml file

```
<property column="yourDateInDB" name="yourDateInJava" type="timestamp"/>
```